# colors and border setting in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to set the border and color for my pdf cells.

```
PdfPCell[] headingcell = new PdfPCell[] {
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc_abc_abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("abc", font9)),
            };

            headingcell[0].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[1].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[2].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[3].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[4].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[5].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[6].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[7].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[8].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[9].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[10].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[11].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[12].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            headingcell[13].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;

            headingcell[0].BorderWidth = 0;                
            headingcell[1].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[2].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[3].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[4].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[5].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[6].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[7].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[8].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[9].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[10].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[11].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[12].BorderWidth = 0;
            headingcell[13].BorderWidth = 0;
            table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(headingcell));
```

I am able to achieve what I want with this coding, but I would like to ask is there a more efficient way to achieve this? Because these codes is so long only for this small thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
{
    headingcell[i].BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
    headingcell[i].BorderWidth = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your parameters into an array or an dictionary, for example:

```
      List<object[]> data= new List<object[]>
        {
            new object[] {"abc", "font9"},
            new object[] {"abc", "font9"},
            new object[] {"abc", "font9"},
            new object[] {"abc", "font9"},
            new object[] {"abc_abc_abc", "font9"},
            // etc...
        };
```

Then you can do all of your work with a single LINQ statement:

```
        PdfCell[] cells = data.Select(x =>
        {
           return new PdfCell(new Phrase(x[0], x[1]))
            {
                BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY,
                BorderWidth = 0
            };
        }).ToArray();
```